# SwipeRefreshLayout not allowing listview row item horizontal scrolling

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, swiperefreshlayout

I have viewPager inside that there is 2 Fragment. Inside fragment1.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background_color"
android:focusable="false"> <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView_feed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animationCache="true"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:divider="@color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true" /></android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout></RelativeLayout>
```

And in listView_feed there is another horizontal_listview inside listView_feed each row but while adding inside SwipeRefreshLayout it will not allowing horizontal_listview horizontal scroll and focus moved to pager. But if I move listView_feed outside SwipeRefreshLayout then each listView_feed child can scroll horizontally.

Comment: Try making the SwipeRefreshLayout the root element.

Comment: Not working same issue @Malith Lakshan

Answer (score 0):

Thank you who tried and see my question. Finally I found one good [library](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/android-PullRefreshLayout) by using it I was able to achieve my requirement. But it is not same as SwipeRefershLayout. It is refreshing in header not over Listview but it works great.